# Qual a diferença entre @yield e @include no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

Estou aprendendo `Laravel 5.3`, `@yield` e @include me parecem muito a mesma coisa, a única diferença que eu conheço é que @include injeta as variáveis do ***pai*** e também pode incluir outras variáveis.

- Qual a diferença entre `@yield` e `@include`?
- Quando devo usar `@yield`?
- Quando devo usar `@include`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> `@yield` é usada para exibir o conteúdo de uma determinada seção, que é definido por `@section` que é responsável em definir uma seção de conteúdo. Um exemplo são os `templates` que servirão de base para várias páginas.

***Exemplo*** *setor administrativo*:

`master.blade.php` (***`template`***):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">        
        <div class="panel-body">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

`roles.blade.php`:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    //Contéudo que será diferente para outras páginas
@stop
```

nesse exemplo, tem uma estrutura base para todas páginas que vão utilizar `template` é com `@section` é aonde o conteúdo vai ser exibido na template onde está `@yield`, nesse caso existe a relação entre esses `blade`. `@yield` é  utilizada quando precisar definir ***seções*** em uma `template` (*ou página*) e para funcionar precisa que `@section` correspondente tenha contéudo para ser carregado.

Tem alguns códigos aonde `@yield` é utilizada simplesmente como passagem de valor, **exemplo**:

```
@yield('titulo')
```

*e*

```
@section('titulo', 'Novo titulo');
```

geralmente, são utilizados como sub-títulos dessas outras `views`.

---

> `@include` permite carrega outras `views` (*`sub-views`* com a *nomenclatura de extensão* `.blade.php`) em uma `view` e utilizar as variáveis que foram enviadas a essa `view`.

***Exemplo***:

`erros.blade.php`

```
@if(isset($errors) && count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top: 6px;">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

`cadastro.blade.php`

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    @include('errors')
@stop
```

esse `@include` é bem particular as páginas de cadastros de qualquer tabela, onde os dados serão processados e validados e se houver algum erro esse trecho de código exibe as mensagens dos problemas de validação.

`@include` é diferente nesses aspectos a `@yield`, porque, `@include` é incluir uma pagina em especifico, já `@yield` é para exibir conteúdo de uma seção determinada, que também pode conter `@include`.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade)
- [Extending A Layout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-a-layout)
- [Including Sub-Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views)

Comment: Excelente resposta =D

Comment: Melhor explicação.